# File not being copied from using windows command in Qt

Tags: qt

The following code is not working - file copy from C:\ to D:\

```
QProcess* process = new QProcess();
process->setWorkingDirectory("C:\\Windows\\System32\\");
process->setProgram("cmd.exe");
process->setArguments(qsl << "COPY" << "C:\\Projects\\file.txt" << "D:\\" << "\n\r");
process->start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", qsl); //process->start("cmd.exe") is deprecated// 
if (!process->waitForStarted())
            {
              qDebug() << "The process didn't start" << process->error();
            }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whats wrong with (QFile::copy("C:\\Projects\\file.txt", "D:\\file.txt))[https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html#copy-1]? And for your example - you want `cmd /c ...`

Comment: I have tried QFile::copy("C:\\Projects\\file.txt", "D:\\file.txt); - Didn't work!!
what do you exactly mean by cmd /c? In which line of code is this?

Comment: Note that you are passing a string list (as you should). This means, that the list items, also the `"\n\r"` are _separate arguments_ (which Qt will escape as needed).